# Missing data in DataGridView after import from Excel

Tags: c#, .net

While I am trying to import data from excel, some data of my excel sheet is missing in the `DataGridView`

```
string pathcpnn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(pathcpnn);

OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from[" + textBox2.Text + "$]", con);

 myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

DAtagridview1.datasource=dt;
```

[image: excel sheet]

[image: Data GridView]

Comment: Sorry, but you need to add some additional informations: which library are you using to make the import? Can you post your code?

Comment: Show your code so that others can understand where actually is the misbehaving code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I suggest you read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: To paraphrase the link in Maverick's comment - provide a **short example** that reproduces the problem, not your entire codebase.

Comment: i am using using System.Data.OleDb; this refrence

Comment: You can try with `"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;` in the connection string

Answer (score 0):

string pathcpnn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source =" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;";";

OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(pathcpnn);

OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from[" + textBox2.Text + "$]", con);

myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

DAtagridview1.datasource=dt;